# Android view disappear after doing scale animation?

Tags: android, animation, view, scaleanimation

I would like to do a scale animation on an image. When I click on it, it should be scaled up and it will be scaled down after clicking it again.

However, the image will be disappeared after it scale down.

Here's my code,

```
    private void scaleAnimation() {
        if (mIsViewExpanded) {
            // collapse
            ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1.25f, 1f, 1.25f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            scaleAnimation.setDuration(DELAY);
            scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
            view.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
        } else {
            // expand
            ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 1.25f, 1f, 1.25f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            scaleAnimation.setDuration(DELAY);
            scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
            view.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
        }
    }
```

Do you guys have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: you should set mIsViewExpanded true when  expand and false when collapse

Comment: hi rainash, I already set it in the other function.

Comment: just set in scaleAnimation() and try again

Comment: And if you set `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in the end?

Comment: hmm... that's weird. it's not working at all.